# CSS nested class selectors not working

Tags: html, css

This is an almost constant problem I'm having with classes not doing anything. In this case I am trying to make a button effect for a class called button within a class called sidebar.

HTML

```
<nav class="sidebar">

<div class="button">

<a href="C:\Users\x0268255\Documents\cats_page\North_America.html" North 
America> North America </a>
</div>

</nav>
```

For the CSS it does not matter what I use. Using a .button or any combination does nothing. For example:

```
a {
    border: 3px outset blue;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: hsl(210, 64%, 48%);
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}
```

Will do nothing. Neither will .button or div.button . If I apply a style to sidebar it works but I want individual links to be in individual buttons to make it obvious it's a list of clickable links.

Comment: `North America` inside the a tag (outside any attribute)... this is no valid html markup. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Works fine for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/cb42ckrj/). The error is not in the shown code fragments.

Comment: Does it do nothing, or is just the border missing? I think your a needs to be a block element for borders. Try "display:block;".
Also, check if a isn't changed elsewhere using the f12 developer tools in your browser. If so, a more specific selector like "div.button>a"

Comment: If you have `.button a` after `a` in your stylesheet, it will override the `a`.

Answer (score -2):

`a` is not a block element and so padding and border and background color not work properly. Make it inline-block:

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 3px outset blue;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: hsl(210, 64%, 48%);
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}
```

alse make sure that you don't overrdide `a` styles by `.button a` or `div a` or `.sidebar a` after styling `a`.

Comment: But it works... see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/cb42ckrj/). I don't know what's the problem, but it's not that kind of problem you try to solve with your answer.

Comment: The block styles acts weird on inline element and there is no guarantee how it will be rendered. In the fiddle above I can not see the top padding however the double size padding is applied on its bottom (Chrome  61.0.3163.100)

Comment: Compare the result with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb42ckrj/2/)

Comment: Sure. I know that. but the questioner said: _This is an almost constant problem I'm having with classes not doing anything_ and later _For the CSS it does not matter what I use. Using a .button or any combination does nothing._ His problem is: the style is not applying to the elements. your answer fixes wrong styling / the issue of styling inline elements with block css properties. But it's not a solution for the question

Comment: In my opinion the problem is constant and no combination works because he applies block styles on inline elements in all combinations.